# easy way to add jar dependencies to a scratch file in intelij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have created a scratch file `scratch.java`

I added a new plain java module that contains the following:

[image]

I have specified the dependency in the build configuration for the scratch file:

The dependencies are not found when I try and edit and build the scratch file.
**How can I easily add dependencies to a scratch file in intelij?**

[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer, but if I were you I would just keep a scratch Maven project handy somewhere.  Instead of manually adding JARs, you just cut and paste a few thing into the POM, and then let IntelliJ worry about building and other things.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In **Run/Debug Configuration...** setting you can make your scratch-file to be run using a specific classpath or module. Just change `Use classpath of module` or  `Program arguments`.

Comment: make sure that if the module has a pom that you've added it to the maven projects plugin, otherwise it won't show up in the list.

Comment: if i have jar files in a lib folder , can you help how to add that lib folder as dependency for scratch file

Comment: This would allow me to run the scratch file, but I get compile-time errors on building it saying that these modules are not found

Comment: It doesn't work . Throws error `Error: Could not find or load main class Scratch` if I select classpath.